# go http.Server sends no response even though the handler calls w.Write()

Tags: go, http

I have the following handler function:

```
    return func(r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter) {
        d, err := json.Marshal(val)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("JSON marshal %T failed: %w", val, err))
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(d)))
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        w.Header().Set("Connection", "close")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        num, err := w.Write(d)
        olog.V(5).Info("success", "method", r.Method, "url", r.URL.String(), "status", http.StatusOK, "length", len(d), "num", num, "error", err)
    }
```

It responds to a HTTP request, and I see the following log statement:

```
I0823 15:02:43.332251                  143 gpthelper/service.go:75] msg=success method=POST url=/extract status=200 length=568 num=568 error=null
```

From this, I can draw the conclusion that the ResponseWriter.Write() call succeeded, claiming it consumed 568 bytes of body.

There is no subsequent panic or error log, and the server keeps responding to requests after this.

However, the curl request that ended up calling this function, claims it got no response:

```
ubuntu@mpt-30b:~$ curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"id":"test", "data":"... some payload ..."}' http://localhost:8000/extract
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Running `tcpdump` shows that there is, indeed, no data being sent from the server:

Acking the initial request payload:

```
17:04:48.460267 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.34032: Flags [.], ack 362, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 2160507848 ecr 2160507848], length 0
    0x0000:  0000 0304 0006 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800  ................
    0x0010:  4500 0034 7625 4000 4006 c69c 7f00 0001  E..4v%@.@.......
    0x0020:  7f00 0001 1f40 84f0 3083 10b0 25fe 05fa  .....@..0...%...
    0x0030:  8010 01fd fe28 0000 0101 080a 80c6 bbc8  .....(..........
    0x0040:  80c6 bbc8                                ....
```

Does some processing, and then sends no response, just FIN:

```
17:04:59.049025 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.34032: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 362, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2160518436 ecr 2160507848], length 0
    0x0000:  0000 0304 0006 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800  ................
    0x0010:  4500 0034 7626 4000 4006 c69b 7f00 0001  E..4v&@.@.......
    0x0020:  7f00 0001 1f40 84f0 3083 10b0 25fe 05fa  .....@..0...%...
    0x0030:  8011 0200 fe28 0000 0101 080a 80c6 e524  .....(.........$
    0x0040:  80c6 bbc8                                ....
17:04:59.049463 IP localhost.34032 > localhost.8000: Flags [F.], seq 362, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2160518437 ecr 2160518436], length 0
    0x0000:  0000 0304 0006 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800  ................
    0x0010:  4500 0034 ae60 4000 4006 8e61 7f00 0001  E..4.`@.@..a....
    0x0020:  7f00 0001 84f0 1f40 25fe 05fa 3083 10b1  .......@%...0...
    0x0030:  8011 0200 fe28 0000 0101 080a 80c6 e525  .....(.........%
    0x0040:  80c6 e524                                ...$
17:04:59.049495 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.34032: Flags [.], ack 363, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2160518437 ecr 2160518437], length 0
    0x0000:  0000 0304 0006 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800  ................
    0x0010:  4500 0034 7627 4000 4006 c69a 7f00 0001  E..4v'@.@.......
    0x0020:  7f00 0001 1f40 84f0 3083 10b1 25fe 05fb  .....@..0...%...
    0x0030:  8010 0200 fe28 0000 0101 080a 80c6 e525  .....(.........%
    0x0040:  80c6 e525                                ...%
```

The route to that response function is registered using Gorilla mux.Router (I understand Gorilla is sunset, but it's been very stable for a long time. Given that the request gets to the right place, I doubt that's the problem here.)

So, what in the go http.Server implementation, causes this behavior? Specifically, it seems like it's waiting until the `w.Write(d)` call succeeds, before it decides to actually not send any data, but instead just close the socket.
Also, I've tried adding a cast to `http.Flusher` and calling `Flusher.Flush()` after `w.Write()` and, while I've verified the cast works and the call is made, it doesn't improve the outcome.

Using go version go1.19.6 linux/amd64, running on Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS.
This happens both inside kubernetes on AWS, and on a root shell host at lambdalabs, so it's unlikely to be infrastructure related.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the entire implementation of the `http.Server` and bufio, it turns out this was because I had misunderstood the `WriteTimeout` parameter to `http.Server`.

Based on the documentation description of "WriteTimeout is the maximum duration before timing out writes of the response," I thought it meant "when I have queued data to the other end, but it doesn't read it, time out after this long" but it actually means "when I, the server, have spent more than this amount of time without reading a header, time out." (which is actually spelled out in the next step of the docs, so, next time: don't miss that bit!)

The `WriteTimeout` must also include any processing time on the server side.
Increasing this value to compensate, fixes this problem.

Now, it would have been helpful for the (eventual) call to `Write()` to return the deadline exceeded error, so that I had some chance to capture and log this error, but the implementation just swallows it. I can't find a good way to extract/detect this error in any other way.